# How to use Koin sharedViewModel() and NavigationComponent navArgs() together

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, koin

I'm trying to inject a `sharedViewModel` using `arguments` as the `key`.

```
private val args: TrackDetailFragmentArgs by navArgs()
private val trackVM: TrackDetailViewModel by sharedViewModel(key = args.trackId.toString())
```

This is the error I get

```
 Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.marcheoutdoor.fragments.TrackDetailFragment: calling Fragment constructor caused an exception
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:474)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.instantiateFragment(FragmentNavigator.java:165)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:181)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:50)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:797)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:782)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:719)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:705)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:837)
```

I'm guessing the `arguments` are null when the `sharedViewModel` is injected, but I'm not sure.

How can I use the `trackId` as a `key` (or maybe as a `parameter`?) while getting it from the `arguments`?

**EDIT1**: I tried using the direct `arguments` call and it works

```
private val trackVM: TrackDetailViewModel by sharedViewModel(key = arguments?.getLong("trackId").toString())
```

So I'm guessing there's something wrong with the `navArgs()` call.

**EDIT2**: as suggested by [Commonware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware), `EDIT1` doesn't really work, it just pass a `null` `key` to the method. I'm losing hope that there's a way to use this approach.

Comment: I am surprised that your edit worked. At the time the `TrackDetailFragment` is instantiated, there is no arguments `Bundle`, as the `Bundle` gets attached to the fragment not via a constructor, but via a `setArguments()` call. Are you sure that your edit really works, or is it simply not crashing due to your safe call? IOW, are you really getting your `trackId` value?

Comment: Ah... I might have been misguided by the nullability of `key`. I changed all the related code and I'm now using `sharedViewModel { parametersOf(args.activityId) }`, it works and I'm sure of it (I checked). Now I'm trying to understand if this parameter works as a key too.